# C# Silicon Labs CP2102 using CP210xManufacturing dll usage

Tags: c#, dll

I am trying to use the Silicon Labs CP210xManufacturing.dll to read and set some values in the 2102 chip. I can read the product ID and the Product String, but I can't seem to read the serial number. The device shows up fine in the code from SI labs to do this, so I know the device is working.

Here's my code (I'm using Studio 2008, but it also shows this in Studio 2012);

and here is where I got the dll;

http://www.silabs.com/products/mcu/Pages/USBXpress.aspx

if you uncomment the following line, Studio shows the error below;

line 30 //result = CSepSIChipWrap.getDeviceSerialNumber(siRef, serialNumber, ref length, true);

Error   2   The best overloaded method match for 'CS_2102_Testing.CSepSIChipWrap.getDeviceSerialNumber(ref System.IntPtr, ref System.Text.StringBuilder, ref byte, bool)' has some invalid arguments

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;


namespace CS_2102_Testing
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IntPtr siRef = IntPtr.Zero;
            uint numDevice = 0;
            var result = CSepSIChipWrap.getNumberOfDevices(ref numDevice);
            result = CSepSIChipWrap.open(0, ref siRef);

            ushort pid = 0;
            result = CSepSIChipWrap.getDevicePid(siRef, ref pid);

            StringBuilder productString = new StringBuilder();
            byte length = 0;
            result = CSepSIChipWrap.getDeviceProductString(siRef, productString, ref length, true);


            StringBuilder serialNumber = new StringBuilder();
            byte serialLength = 0;
            //result = CSepSIChipWrap.getDeviceSerialNumber(siRef, serialNumber, ref length, true);



            Console.WriteLine(pid.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(productString.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class CSepSIChipWrap
    {
        private const string CP210xManu = "CP210xManufacturing.dll";

        [DllImport(CP210xManu, EntryPoint = "CP210x_GetNumDevices")]
        public static extern int getNumberOfDevices(
        [In, Out] ref UInt32 deviceNumb);

        [DllImport(CP210xManu, EntryPoint = "CP210x_Open")]
        public static extern int open(
        [In] UInt32 deviceNumb,
        [In, Out] ref IntPtr deviceHandle);

        [DllImport(CP210xManu, EntryPoint = "CP210x_Close")]
        public static extern int close(
        [In, Out] ref IntPtr deviceHandle);

        [DllImport(CP210xManu, EntryPoint = "CP210x_GetDeviceProductString",
        CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public static extern int getDeviceProductString(
        [In, Out] IntPtr deviceHandle,
        [In, Out] StringBuilder Product,
        [In, Out] ref byte Length,
        [In] bool ConvertToASCII);

        [DllImport(CP210xManu, EntryPoint = "CP210x_GetDeviceSerialNumber",
        CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public static extern int getDeviceSerialNumber(
        [In, Out] ref IntPtr deviceHandle,
        [In, Out] ref StringBuilder Product,
        [In, Out] ref byte Length,
        [In, Out] bool ConvertToASCII);

        [DllImport(CP210xManu, EntryPoint = "CP210x_GetDeviceVid")]
        public static extern int getDeviceVid(
        [In, Out] ref IntPtr deviceHandle,
        [In, Out] ref ushort Vid);

        [DllImport(CP210xManu, EntryPoint = "CP210x_GetDevicePid")]
        public static extern int getDevicePid(
        [In, Out] IntPtr deviceHandle,
        [In, Out] ref ushort Pid);
    }   

}
```

Comment: Are you programming in C++ or C#?  An answer in C++ may not work if you are programming in C#.

Comment: Since you tagged this as C++, the identifier `ref` needs a definition.

Comment: I'm writing in C#. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Tay Were you able to solve this problem?

Comment: I was, but don't recall what I did offhand. If you need it, I'll see if I can dig it up.

Comment: I am getting DeviceVID value as 1028 and Device PID value as 844. I am confused about the values. It should be like 0404 etc. I think its pointer to the 2 Byte value. But How can I retrieve the value?